# Unable to instantiate application, I have added permissions & the emulator has external storage

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can't see what is causing this error. I have only tried the app in the emulator but the emulator does have external storage, I am trying to write an image to the external storage, then open it in the gallery.

The button simply doesn't work when I click it.

Here is my logcat:

```
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
01-01 12:03:21.963: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
```

Code - the brackets seem to of messed up, but you get the jist:

```
    package com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Random;

    import com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.R;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContextWrapper;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Challenge1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.challenge1_layout);

        Button hint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hint_button_1);
        Button answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.solution_button_1);

        hint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CreateAlert();
            }
        });

        answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Converts the file to a bitmap
                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.challenge1_solution);
                Bitmap challenge1_solution = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable)
                        .getBitmap();

                // Saves the file to internal storage
                SaveImage(challenge1_solution);

                // Open gallery & image
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                        .parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            }
        });
    }

    private void CreateAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Hint")
                .setMessage("Use the print() statement").show();
    }

    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "challenge_1.png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.SplashScreen"
            android:label="Welcome!" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="Choose a challenge" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 1 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge1"
            android:label="Challenge 1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE1" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 2 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge2"
            android:label="Challenge 2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 3 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge3"
            android:label="Challenge 3" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE3" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 4 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge4"
            android:label="Challenge 4" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE4" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 5 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge5"
            android:label="Challenge 5" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE5" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <!-- Challenge 6 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge6"
            android:label="Challenge 6" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE6" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 7 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge7"
            android:label="Challenge 7" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE7" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 8 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge8"
            android:label="Challenge 8" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE8" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 9 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge9"
            android:label="Challenge 9" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE9" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 10 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge10"
            android:label="Challenge 10" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE10" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 11 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge11"
            android:label="Challenge 11" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE11" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 12 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge12"
            android:label="Challenge 12" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE12" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 13 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge13"
            android:label="Challenge 13" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE13" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 14 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge14"
            android:label="Challenge 14" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE14" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 15 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge15"
            android:label="Challenge 15" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE15" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 16 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge16"
            android:label="Challenge 16" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE16" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 17 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge17"
            android:label="Challenge 17" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE17" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 18 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge18"
            android:label="Challenge 18" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE18" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 19 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge19"
            android:label="Challenge 19" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE19" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 20 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge20"
            android:label="Challenge 20" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE20" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 21 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge21"
            android:label="Challenge 21" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE21" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 22 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge22"
            android:label="Challenge 22" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE22" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 23 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge23"
            android:label="Challenge 23" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE23" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 24 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge24"
            android:label="Challenge 24" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE24" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Challenge 25 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.Challenge25"
            android:label="Challenge 25" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xProGames.pythonchallengesforbeginners.challenges.CHALLENGE25" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you used any Skeleton Application class??

Comment: Nope, I will update the question with the code.

Comment: show your Manifest file

Comment: did u check that the needed check boxes are checked in `Java Build Path` in `Properties` ?

Comment: No, which boxes need to be checked?

Comment: Right click on project then click Properties, there u can see the Java build path

Comment: I have the following ticked: http://gyazo.com/16c740c1dbf2e521a06ea444fa78ff36

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace than what you have listed here?